# Is there any analogy of symmetric matrix in higher-degree homogeneous polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, symmetric-matrices, projective-varieties

In quadric forms, we know that we can use symmetric matrix to describe it,  and by diagonalizing it we can determine the isomorphic classes of them as projective varieties (use its rank and dimension, see Wedhorn's AG, the last part of chapter 1). But I want to ask is there any analogy of symmetric matrix for curves of higher degrees in $\mathbb P^n$? If it can be realized, can we reduce the research of curves in $\mathbb P^n$ to "that" object? Thank you.

Comment: Those are called tensors. You can visualize them as "higher dimension" matrices. If vector have dimension 1, matrices have dimension 2, then tensors are the generalization to dimension $n$

Comment: @Exodd I know tensors, but I want to ask can tensors describe homogeneous polynomials as symmetric matrices does? Could you give a further explanation?